# (SSL)How to convert .der file to .cer file?

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl

I followed [How To: DER vs CRT vs CER vs PEM Certificates and How to Convert Them](https://info.ssl.com/how-to-der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-conver-them/), wanting to understand how to set up SSL, but I cannot find a good reference for it.

On my server, I have paid certificates, not self-signed ones, and I want to enable SSL in my apache2 server; within `000-default.conf`, I need to insert the `.cer` file path:

```ini
SSLCertificateFile     /ets/ssl/example.pl.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/ssl/example.key
```

As I understand it, `.der` is an encrypted `.cer` file; should I convert a `.der` to `.cer`, or is my thinking wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Futuire visitors: Note that although all X.509 certificates are DER, *not all DER files are X.509* – plenty of other non-certificate things use DER as well. This thread is strictly about X.509 certificates and not about any other data type.

---

X.509 certificates are *always* in DER format, but they're generally stored in two ways:

1. Raw binary DER (usual extensions: `.der`, `.cer`)
2. Textual, Base64-encoded DER, sometimes called "PEM" (usual extensions: `.crt`, `.pem`)

Note that the extensions aren't really set in stone – `.cer` might be textual, `.crt` might be binary, and so on. You have to actually look inside.

(There is no encryption involved; the certificate is public information.)

To convert one certificate from binary to textual format, you can use:

```sh
openssl x509 -in mycert.der -inform DER -out mycert.pem

# both -inform and -outform default to "PEM" if not specified otherwise
```

Or since it's just Base64,

```bsh
(echo "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----";
 base64 < mycert.der;
 echo "-----END CERTIFICATE-----") > mycert.pem
```

However, whichever way you use, don't forget to **add the certificate chain** (the "issuer" or "intermediate" certs obtained from your CA) to the same PEM file. Most software expects it all in a single file, although Apache used to use a separate SSLCertificateChainFile option in v2.2.x.

Comment: Why not just use `openssl x509 -inform der -in mycert.der -out mycert.cer`?

Comment: So there's no difference if I add `.crt`, `.pem` or `.cer` file to `SSLCertificateFile`? https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them

Comment: @A.Dziedziczak: Most software expects PEM format and won't accept binary DER. (Again, the extension doesn't matter, it's the _contents_ that matter.)